# On choose file set attribute in jQuery

Tags: jquery, onchange, input-type-file

I want to change `visibility` property value from `hidden` to `visible`, when user chooses file in type="file" HTML input. Below is my code:

```
<script>
$("#file_upload").change(function(){
    $("#is_it_uploaded").attr('visibility', 'visible'); // to enable the checkbox
});
</script>

<div class="file_upload">
<input type="file" id="file_upload" name="photo">
</div>

<img src="uploaded.gif" style="visibility: hidden;" id="is_it_uploaded">
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either do:

```
$("#is_it_uploaded").css('visibility', 'visible');
```

or

```
$("#is_it_uploaded").show();
```

Answer (score 1):

`visibility` is a style not an attribute so use [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$("#is_it_uploaded").css('visibility', 'visible');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/js4s18uy/)